# Crushed subplots not occupying the whole plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, colorbar

I don't know why but my subplots are completely crushed instead of occupying the whole plot.

Also, I would like that the subplots have the same length, and the colorbars too. Here it looks like that the first 2 subplots are shorter than the 3rd one because the colorbar is bigger.

Ideally I would like this kind of result : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517915/very-low-quality-result-with-imshow-and-colorbar
but with the quality of pcolormesh (imshow is giving a really bad quality), and with 2 colorbars.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig  = plt.figure()

grid_top = ImageGrid(fig, 211, nrows_ncols = (2, 1),
                     cbar_location = "right",                     
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2) 
grid_bot = ImageGrid(fig, 212, nrows_ncols = (1, 1),
                     cbar_location = "right",                     
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2) 

im1 = grid_top[0].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array1[0])),np.arange(0,len(array1)+1),array1, vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
im2 = grid_top[1].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array2[0])),np.arange(0,len(array2)+1),array2, vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
im3 = grid_bot[0].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array3[0])),np.arange(0,len(array3)+1),array3, vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5, cmap='seismic')

grid_top.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im1)
grid_bot.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im3)

plt.show()
```

Here the result, why is it so crushed and why the subplots are not occupying the whole plot?

[image]

Comment: Try `pcolormesh(...,aspect='auto')`

Comment: there is no attribute "aspect" in pcolormesh. I tried plt.gca().set_aspect('auto') after the pcolormesh, but there is no change.

Comment: try setting `aspect=False` on the `ImageGrid(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set `aspect=False` for the `ImageGrid` instances ([see the docs for ImageGrid here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#imagegrid)) [h/t @daryl]

> aspect
>
> By default (False), widths and heights of axes in the grid are scaled independently. If True, they are scaled according to their data limits (similar to aspect parameter in mpl).

Taking your code, and adding `aspect=False` to `grid_top` and `grid_bot`, yields this:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig  = plt.figure()

grid_top = ImageGrid(fig, 211, nrows_ncols = (2, 1),
                     cbar_location = "right",                     
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2,
                     aspect=False) 
grid_bot = ImageGrid(fig, 212, nrows_ncols = (1, 1),
                     cbar_location = "right",                     
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2,
                     aspect=False) 

# Some random data so the script will run
array1=np.random.rand(10,250)
array2=np.random.rand(10,250)
array3=np.random.rand(10,250)

im1 = grid_top[0].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array1[0])),np.arange(0,len(array1)+1),array1, vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
im2 = grid_top[1].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array2[0])),np.arange(0,len(array2)+1),array2, vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
im3 = grid_bot[0].pcolormesh(np.arange(0,len(array3[0])),np.arange(0,len(array3)+1),array3, vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5, cmap='seismic')

grid_top.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im1)
grid_bot.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im3)

plt.show()
```